# Google Maps Max Zoom does not increase MapType MaxZoom

Tags: typescript, google-maps

I am Working on an WebGIS-Project with Google Maps with an hybrid-Basemap
I am not able to increase above zoom level 22

I already tried:
map.mapTypes.hybrid.maxZoom = 25;
map.setOptions({maxZoom: 25});

Both did only work if I minimize the maxZoomLevel.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increase the maximum zoom level that is available for a given location. [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom) states:

> Most roadmap imagery is available from zoom levels 0 to 18, for
>   example. Satellite imagery varies more widely as this imagery is not
>   generated, but directly photographed.

If you want to know what the highest zoom level is for a given location, use the MaxZoomService. Take a look at [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maxzoom-simple) which is an hybrid map. Try playing around with it in JSFiddle; you'll see that for most locations the maximum zoom level is 21 and setting it beyond that limit like you're trying to do (maxZoom = 25) won't make a difference. It will default back to 21.

Hope this clarifies your question.